# Spring Boot service exception is not caught by @ControllerAdvice exception handler

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have all my api controller methods in a controller with an exception handler annotated with "ControllerAdvice". This way, I can always return a JSON response to the frontend even if an unexpected exception occurs. This works fine for exceptions raised by code in the controller, but for exceptions raised in code in a service method called by the controller, the exception handler isn't used.

I don't want to have to specifically annotate the service to use the same exception handler because it may be called by a controller that we use different exception handling for.

Is there a way to prevent the service from handling the exception itself and instead have the controller's exception handler handle it?

Comment: I should be able to help.  If the service layer is catching the exception (without re-throwing) then the exception will never reach the controller layer.  Post some of your code, maybe I can see the issue.

Comment: There's no way to tell what's going wrong without you posting some code, like Isaac said. But in my experience, exceptions thrown from service methods were always caught. Make sure you have no interceptors that would change/wrap your service method's exceptions.